# My React component does not update in the Safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thought everything was going great. Works perfectly in Chrome, FF, Edge, even IE 11!

The parent component holds all the sate. I pass the bets object to the child component which calculates a count to pass to the grandchild component to display.

The parent state 'bets' is an object with the keys as an ID and the value as an object.

The parent state is correctly changing when I interact with the app. Why will only Safari not update when the parent state changes? (on iOS and MacOS)

Parent

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bets: {}
        };
    }
}
```

Child

```
getBadgeCount = (league) => {
    const bets = this.props.bets;
    let count = 0;
    Object.keys(bets).map((bet) => bets[bet].event.league === league && count++);
    return count;
};

// ...

<ChildItem count={this.getBadgeCount(league)} />
```

GrandChild

```
class GrandChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { count } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {count > 0 && <div>{count}</div>}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I `console.log` the count inside the grandchild render and in the componentDidUpdate and it shows the right number. Is there something apple/safari specific with react I am missing?

Comment: Your code looks fine. How are you updating the state in the `ParentComponent`? Are you using `this.setState` or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using `this.setState({ bets: currentBets })` inside a click handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did solve the very bizarre issue after a few days.

What was happening was I guess the engine in the Safari browser was not re-rendering the little badge icon correctly. I would print out the value inside the DOM, OUTSIDE of the styled badge I was using, and the number would update as expected... Leading me to believe the issue was related to styles.

THEN after removing what I thought was the CSS causing the issue, I noticed that it looked like safari was 'partially' updating the value in the badge. It appears to have half re-rendered, and the previous number collides with the new value... Not sure if this is some obscure problem with the render engine?

[image]

After adding and removing all the CSS one by one, the issue remained so I decided to trick the browser to 'force' render with a simple calculation inside the grandchild where it was being rendered:

```
const safariRenderHack = { opacity: count % 2 ? 1 : 0.99 };

<div style={safariRenderHack}>{count}</div>
```

[image]

Not a great solution but oh well I guess it's fixed. ha

Answer (score 7):

In the case where there are variables being changed based on which you can switch between the styles (opacity: 1 or opacity: 0.99) You can try adding a key to the element which is not being updated in Safari/iOS.

`<div key={new Date()} className={'myComponent'}>{Count}</div>`

I ran into the same problem, this seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

I just run into similar problem.
Safari didn't re-render some texts implemented as:

```
<span>{someValue}</span>
```

On 'someValue' field update, reactJS worked fine (element was requested to render) but Safari re-renders only area of new value (shorter than previous). UI glitches :-/

If I done anything to CSS via Developer tools, element has been rendered again and looks fine :-/

After some tries, I luckily used a **'display: block;'** style property and it starts to re-rendering absolutely fine. Also **'display: inline-block;'** will fix that problem too, if it is needed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where a center positioned span using flexbox inside a div wasn't updating correctly in Safari.

Restyling this div to use display:block solved this rendering issue so this might be worth looking into if anyone runs into the same problem in the future.

P.S. Looking at the styling code now, making the change was actually a much cleaner solution as it reduced the amount of lines from 4 to 1 but this might not be the case for all scenarios of course.

before:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

after: (is a div so display:block is already used)

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using **map** function , **React** looks at the **keys** : 
To identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

**Solution** :

- **Now,** As you use map function u must **Add Key** to the div inside map .
- **Use** a key variable that is connected to the logic behind clicking , so that when clicking the key , the variable is updated and so React will rerender this grandchild div .
  As the following code : 
  `<div key={Count} className={'myComponent'}>{Count}</div>`

PS : I discourage to use Date as a key , because I f u are clicking quickly it glitches , while if u are connecting it with a state with the logic behind clicking , it won't .

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

will-change: transform;

Comment: the question has been asked a year and a half ago

Comment: @Lukianchuk Maxim If you believe this 18 months old question needs a better answer (which in itself is perfectly fine) please explain exactly what and why you are suggesting this code.
You might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be late but what helped me with Safari not re-rendering reused components was:

will-change: opacity;

You may have to experiment which element in your HTML hierarchy to apply this to.
It makes no sense because no opacity was being changed in my case but it did fix the problem. Thank you, Apple...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, community bot. I wanted to help others by providing my solution, my perspective and a waypoint for their own investigation. I am not going to edit it any further.

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this problem. So, I did a short research about it and got the gist as follows:

1. It works by providing the unique key to the element(key={new Date()} works bcz unique even with seconds) which is not rerendering properly say a description as text inside it that changes by button or an event.
2. So what I got as a gist basically, providing the individual key make new dom element to react during reconcilation process rather than changing same value inside the element so basically that element showing object is made unique instead of changing value inside that dom element so I think safari specific it is as it is holding state of the element rendering dynamically. So after providing the key prop you are basically rendering the unique different element(obviously with different text/object inside it). This basically utilizes here the concept of keys while we render a list in react component.